# Custom function with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data frame:

```
a <- data.frame(BEG_D=as.Date(c("2014-01-01","2014-01-01","2014-01-01","2014-01-01","2014-01-01","2014-01-01","2014-01-01","2014-01-08")) , day=c("Mon","Tues","Wed","Thurs","Fri","Satur","Sun","Mon"), WkNo=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2))
```

Here BEG_D represents beginning day of the week (with "2014-01-01" being Sunday). In order to generate rest of the date numbers. I have written a custom function and using the same with ddply:

```
date_generator <- function(f){
    f$seq <- seq(nrow(f))-1
    f$date <- as.Date(f$BEG_D + f$seq)
    return(f)
}

b <- ddply(a,.(WkNo),date_generator)
```

This works fine as the result as in new data frame, I have:

```
seq = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0)
date = c("2014-01-01","2014-01-02","2014-01-03","2014-01-04","2014-01-05","2014-01-06","2014-01-07","2014-01-08")
```

But for my large data frame takes long time. Apart from this there are certain more ddply operations which were taking long time. So I decided to use data.table with the same data.

```
date_generator <- function(f){
    f[,seq := seq(nrow(f))-1]
    f[,.(date = as.Date(BEG_D + seq))]
    return(f)
}

a[,date_generator(.SD),by=.(WkNo)]
```

Doing so threw an error:

> Error in [.data.table(f, , :=(seq, seq(nrow(f)) - 1)) : .SD is locked.
>   Using := in .SD's j is reserved for possible future use; a tortuously
>   flexible way to modify by group. Use := in j directly to modify by
>   group by reference.

What is the right way to write this custom function with data.table and why ddply is so slow for large data frame?

Comment: I think you're looking for `a[, newdate := BEG_D + 1:.N - 1, by=WkNo]` (I don't use plyr and so can't compare.)

Comment: Thanks @Frank ..Indeed it work fine for data table case...Don't have enough reputation to like your answer though :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the standard way to do that in a data.table:

```
a[, date := BEG_D + 1:.N - 1, by=WkNo]
```

The variable `.N` stores `nrow(.SD)`, the size of the `by` group. I'd recommend having a look at the excellent [introductory materials](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) for the package to get a sense of its idioms.

Comment: @RYoda Because the question is tagged with data.table and pretty clearly pertains to it, I don't think `library(data.table)` is necessary. And I'm not a fan of reproducing the OPs entire example code in my answer. If you want to make them consistent, maybe edit the OP's code (which should create a data.table).